# SQL sequence jump from single digits to 1000 then 2000. How do I make it go back to the original sequence?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

[image]

Here is the stored procedure I used to insert and generate a ticket id .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertServiceEvent]
@ClientID int,
@EventDate datetime,
@Phone nchar(10),
@Contact nvarchar(30),
@NewTicketID int OUTPUT
AS
 --*********************************************************************
--** Add a service event
--*********************************************************************
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @ErrCode int

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceEvents] ([ClientID],[EventDate],[Phone],[Contact])
VALUES (@ClientID, @EventDate, @Phone, @Contact)

SELECT @ErrCode = @@ERROR, @NewTicketID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

I don't know what happened and it just suddenly change the sequence. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: MSSQL or MySQL?

Comment: Hi, it is MSSQL. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Correct the table, try this.

Backup first, verify backup works, This should Reseed the table

```
DELETE A
FROM [dbo].[ServiceEvents] AS A
WHERE A.TicketID > 8

    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[dbo].[ServiceEvents]', RESEED, 9)
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Please note this will remove all records, greater than with the ticket id greater than 8, Backup them up if needed

Comment: Hi, I got the error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."

Comment: What version of MSSQL are you using?

Comment: Version 13. It's in my Visual Studio.

Comment: I got another error :( "Checking identity information: current identity value '2006'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator."

Comment: I kinda fixed it if you would call it fixed but I had to create another database. :( but I will keep the code you gave if this happened again. Thank you very much!